# DateOffset: Week of Month

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Encountered a strange problem while trying to generate a date range of the second Thursday of each quarter start, beginning in March.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import *

start = datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2012, 12, 31)

startrng = pd.bdate_range(start,end,freq='BQS-MAR')
startrng = startrng + pd.datetools.WeekOfMonth(week=1,weekday=3)

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(startrng)),index=startrng)
```

I get the following results:

```
2010-03-11   -0.585671
2010-06-10   -1.201917
2010-09-09   -0.063487
2010-12-09    0.221270
2011-03-10   -0.239836
2011-06-09    0.256052
2011-09-08    1.074758
2011-12-08    0.962388
2012-03-08   -1.601438
2012-06-14    0.854736
2012-09-13    1.532970
2012-12-13   -0.084027
```

While most of the date offset works, 2012-06-14 is actually the 3rd Thursday of the month, with 2012-06-01 starting on a Friday. I have to generate a date range going back a couple of years and it is not productive to manually check for all the dates generated.

Is there another method to produce the correct set of results instead?

Comment: I just looked at the calendar, and 2012-06-14 **is** the 2nd Thursday of the month of June. The 21st would be the 3rd Thursday.

Comment: the 2nd xday of the month will always be >=8 and <=14.

Comment: @Tyanna That's a major doh moment. In that case I would need to change my criteria to return Thursday of the second week in the month. Thanks for pointing that stupid oversight out.

Comment: The correct term should actually be the business day before the 2nd Friday of the month:  

 `startrng = startrng + pd.datetools.WeekOfMonth(week=1,weekday=4) - pd.datetools.BDay()`

  
This would produce the intended results. It was that obvious.

Comment: Two things: 1) Does your edit show the code that produced the 'wrong' results?  If not, you should change it back. 2) Go ahead and post your own answer to this question, and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
startrng = startrng + pd.datetools.WeekOfMonth(week=1,weekday=4) - pd.datetools.BDay()
```